# Conditions that makes that the set of bounded functions is separable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Consider $$B=\{f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \mid \text{ $f$ is a bounded function}\}$$ with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Study conditions that make $B$ separable.

I am trying to use that a normed space is separable if and only if, $B$ contains a dense subspace with numerable dimension.

Comment: Look at the case in which $A$ is finite. In that case look at functions $A\to\mathbb{Q}$. Then, for $A$ infinite, review the proof that $\ell^{\infty}$ is not separable (i.e. look at the characteristic functions of finite subsets).

Comment: @EEE If $A=\mathbb N,$ then there are only countably many characteristic functions of finite subsets.

Comment: @zhw. Really! And you found that out all by yourself? Amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $A=\{1,2,\dots ,n\},$ then $B=\mathbb R^n$ with the $\|\,\|_\infty$ norm. If $A=\mathbb N,$ then the set of all binary sequences is a subset of $B.$